# Problem in Steam game (CS:GO) Numpad

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, games, steam, numpad

I installed Steam, and I was playing Counter Strike Global Offensive. 
The problem is that, Numpad Enter key is not working. Basically, I binded Enter key on Numpad in ingame, but it seems like not working. 
Bind Command - bind "kp_enter" "buy vesthelm"

When I write any command in game console, like "volume 0.1" or any command in console, and hit Enter (numpad), it doesn't work, so I have to press the Enter (main key) to return. 
Rest of the key on numpad is working, it just the Enter key on numpad is not working.

Secondly, Enter key (Numpad) is working outside game, like in terminal, browser, gedit etc. It's just not working inside game.

If anyone else face this problem and knows the solution, please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way, you can bind kp_enter key. Instead you can use this command - bind "enter" "buy vesthelm"

kp_enter is not bindable, follow this post - https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Counter-Strike-Global-Offensive/issues/51